# Revert to a local history label for a group of files in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I have recently discovered `Put Label` feature in intellij idea and noticed that we can put label on a group of files by right clicking on a changelist and selecting `Put Label`. This helps to tag current state of working copy so that we can revert to it at later point of time without committing the changes in git.
Although I can revert an individual file from the changelist to the labelled local history tag but I can't find the option to revert all the files in the changelist (which are part of label) to the labelled history? I have tried looking around the documentation and other stackoverflow questions but they all talk about reverting a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such feature avaible.

Please feel free to submit a feature request:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/